# Where can I find CPU cooler footprint drawings?

Tags: motherboard, specifications, layout, cpu-cooler

I want to get on making a simple bracket for my watercooling block for my new socket 1366 motherboard but it has not arrived yet.

Is there somewhere I can find the scale drawing (with measurements) of the PCB footprint for the cooler for this socket?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://download.intel.com/design/processor/designex/320837.pdf

from page 52+

Comment: that level of detail for what you can and cannot do around the heatsink is just plain awesome, good find!